# How to parse xml file which has special characters in attribute values to java.parser not accepting .how to replace special character

Tags: .net, sql, xml, t-sql

I am trying to parse a xml file in java using DOM OR SAX.

the problem is while parsing , if my xml contains atteibute values as special character like `< > "` , then parser throws `ParserException`.

for example xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc>
     <check name="bike" value="apache<is good model">
     <check name="car" value="tata "sumo">
</abc>
```

In this example xml element `<check>` has an attribute value and it contains `<` or `"` .

The parser takes it as invalid and throws parser exception.

Now my problem is before parsing xml file to parser, detect that special character in xml file attribute values and have to replace with symbol.

eg:

if xml contains `<`

```
<check name="bike" value="apache<is good model">
```

replace with space

```
<check name="bike" value="apache is good model">
```

Please give me suggestions. In what method it can be done...can we do it using XSD...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`<` and `>` are predefined entities in XML and cannot be accepted as part of attributes or values. For reference to list of valid XML & HTML characters check the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) page

If you wish to use `<` as XML values, use [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) tag instead

```
<element  attr="elemAttr">
<value>
<![CDATA[< allowed here]]>
</value>
</element>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the input, replace the offending `<` characters with `&amp;lt;`, which the parser should accept.

If you don't have control over the input, figure out how to catch the exception.